# CSS - Set height according to width

Tags: html, css

Can I set height in CSS using the width? This is what I have now:

```
width: 22.5%;
height: width*2.25;
background: #fff url("images/image_bg.png");
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
background-size: cover;
border: 0.5px solid #ddd;
```

The width of the divs are always the same, but the hights have very slight differences, which makes the backgrounds for them not fit properly. If I can set the hight to scale with the width it would be perfect.

Answer (score 8):

> **padding**
>   ...
>   Percentages:    refer to width of containing block
>   http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#propdef-padding-right

A little known, but very useful, trick with the padding property is that, if the value provided is a percentage, the computed value will be a percentage of the computed **width** of the **containing block**

To keep the **aspect ratio** intact, use `padding-bottom: X%`.

- If you want the **height** to be the same as the **width** and the **width** is set to **25%** (of the containing block) then then you would set `padding-bottom: 25%` on the element.
- If you want the **height** to be half of the **width** and the **width** is **25%** (of the containing block) then you would set `padding-bottom: 12.5%`
- If you want the **height** to be **2.25** times the **width** and the **width** is **22.5%** then multiply that percentage by **2.25** which gives you **56.25%** and apply that percentage e.g.
  `padding-bottom: 56.25%`

```css
#keep-ratio {
  width: 22.5%; /* 22.5% of the parent's width*/
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* (25% of the parent's width) * 2.25 */
  background: #fff url("//lorempixel.com/400/400");
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  border: 0.5px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div id="keep-ratio"></div>
```

Comment: I know this trick, but you are the first to exactly point to the standard, thank you.

Comment: @intijk you may be interested in [this failed attempt at a canonical question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31013181/4639281)

Comment: I saw this. I tried the padding-top action, seems different browser has different action when action status goes complex, so I finally use the javascript to achieve my purpose.