# Table with frozen header with vertical text

Tags: jquery, css, html, html-table

I wish to create a table where the thread is frozen and the labels in the thead are orientated in a vertical manner. My attempt is below, however there are a number of issues with this implementation since I am very new to css.

1. One thing I don't like about my solution is that it is not obvious that there are more rows to be scrolled into view as the scroll bar is hidden until you start scrolling the table. Is there a way of making the scroll bar permanently visible?
2. There is also a large scape at the top of the thead above where the party names are displayed. I can make this gap bigger by playing around with the values in th.vertical but I cant eliminate it. How can I force the thead to be only as high as the text it contains?
3. Finally, I would like the vertical text in the thead to be centred with respect to the column values but I haven't figured out how to do this. How might I do this?
4. I would also like to be able to sort on any column.

```css
table thead tr {
  display: block;
}

table th,
table td {
  width: 75px; //fixed width
}

div.vertical {
  margin-left: -100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 210px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Safari/Chrome */
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Firefox */
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* Opera */
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* IE 9 */
}

th.vertical {
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  text-align: left;
}

table tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<table class='vrt-header'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th class="vertical">
        <div class="vertical">Republican</div>
      </th>
      <th class="vertical">
        <div class="vertical">Democrat</div>
      </th>
      <th class="vertical">
        <div class="vertical">Libertarian</div>
      </th>
      <th class="vertical">
        <div class="vertical">Green</div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Alabama
      </td>
      <td>
        65
      </td>
      <td>
        25
      </td>
      <td>
        10
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        Alaska
      </td>
      <td>
        75
      </td>
      <td>
        15
      </td>
      <td>
        10
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        Arizona
      </td>
      <td>
        55
      </td>
      <td>
        40
      </td>
      <td>
        5
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        Arkansas
      </td>
      <td>
        65
      </td>
      <td>
        25
      </td>
      <td>
        10
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        California
      </td>
      <td>
        25
      </td>
      <td>
        65
      </td>
      <td>
        3
      </td>
      <td>
        7
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You're asking 4 questions in one. Try breaking them up into multiple questions. It makes it easier to answer and more likely for other people to have a related issue.

Comment: Not sure if i entirely understood the question . A) fixed column's width makes this much easier to deal with, is this what you always want ? B) did you consider writing-mode instead position+transform ? C) scrollbar is usually around 1.2rem width, does the padding helps here ?  D) If div are inline-block, then text-align is fine . Here a codepen to test  from this comment : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YvrMeN (inspired from https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/EKQKBe & ) else rotation in the flux via peticularity from  vertical margin/padding https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Cqkig

Comment: There is also position:sticky to look at if you did not https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Lrzvox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've played with your code…

1. I don't know about another way to always show the scrollbar than `overflow-y: scroll;`.
2. I modified all the styling of your headers, but I couldn't find an easy way to automatically adjust the height after your `transform`. I used a fixed value.
3. The new styling is correcting this point.
4. I suggest you to try and read about the [Stupid-Table-Plugin](https://joequery.github.io/Stupid-Table-Plugin/) for jQuery to easily sort a table.

… Plus, I added:

- Some styling on `:hover` to highlight the action on the `th`s.
- An alternation of color for the rows, using the `:nth-of-type()` selector.

… and I ended-up with this snippet:

```js
// Doc here: https://joequery.github.io/Stupid-Table-Plugin/
$("#simpleTable").stupidtable();
```

```css
table thead,
table tbody {
  display: block;
}

table tbody {
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: scroll; /* To make the scroll bar always visible */
}

thead th {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer; /* change cursor to show we can do an action */
  height: 90px;
  background: #ccc;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

thead th:hover {
  background: #ccf; /* Styling on hover */
}

thead th p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  text-align: left;
}

table th,
table th p,
table td {
  width: 75px;
}

table td {
  text-align: center;
}

table tr td:first-of-type {
  text-align: left;
}

table tr:nth-of-type(odd) td {
  background: #eee;
}

table tr:nth-of-type(even) td {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stupidtable/1.1.3/stupidtable.min.js"></script>

<table id="simpleTable" class='vrt-header'>

  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-sort="string"></th>
      <th data-sort="int">
        <p>Republican</p>
      </th>
      <th data-sort="int">
        <p>Democrat</p>
      </th>
      <th data-sort="int">
        <p>Libertarian</p>
      </th>
      <th data-sort="int">
        <p>Green</p>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>
        Alabama
      </td>
      <td>
        65
      </td>
      <td>
        25
      </td>
      <td>
        10
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        Alaska
      </td>
      <td>
        75
      </td>
      <td>
        15
      </td>
      <td>
        10
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        Arizona
      </td>
      <td>
        55
      </td>
      <td>
        40
      </td>
      <td>
        5
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        Arkansas
      </td>
      <td>
        65
      </td>
      <td>
        25
      </td>
      <td>
        10
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        California
      </td>
      <td>
        25
      </td>
      <td>
        65
      </td>
      <td>
        3
      </td>
      <td>
        7
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        ?
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
      <td>
        0
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>


</table>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Lets say I renamed California to SouthernCalifornia (one word), then the width of the first column is not mirrored in the table header, as seen in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/61avLpzr/3/. How would you rectify this?

Comment: @Baz I think the easier way is to give a fixed `width` to the first column (see the beginning of the CSS in this snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/awc80hkg/1/)

Answer (score 2):

1) This is probably on a mac, which uses overlay scrollbars by default. Chrome and Safari support webkit-scroll properties that let you make it always visible, but not sure if you can override that in Firefox.

2) You may be running into the [UA style sheet](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#tables) 's `th` entry: `td, th { padding: 1px; }` You can override it with `th { padding: 0px; }`

3) What you want is actually the default behavior of a table. But it isn't working for two reasons. This might be the toughest to tackle on your own, without using an off-the-shelf component. So unless you're doing this as an exercise I suggest not trying to reinvent the wheel. Instead, find a jquery plugin or angular component or something that provides this. I don't think it's possible to do all this (including rotating the headers) in a cross-browser compatible way without writing a bunch of javascript.

First reason is that setting `div.vertical { position:absolute }` takes them out of normal flow; the `th` positions its normal-flow children to align with the whole column, but not `position:absolute` stuff.

Second is you subtly created 3 tables because of `tr { display:block }` and the `tbody {display:block}` that allows scrolling. The layout code (approximately) sees them as a regular `<div>`s so sees `<table><thead><div>...</div></thead><div>....</div></table>` and creates a table cell, row, and section (aka tbody) to hold each `<div>`. Then inside that `div` it sees `tr` so creates a `table` to hold them.

So the columns in the table that lives under `thead > tr` aren't the same columns that hold your data. So even if you fixed the first reason, you'd still be contending with this.

Here's chrome's layout tree (ignore the hex):

```
 LayoutBlockFlow 0x23e069224010         HTML
    LayoutBlockFlow 0x23e069224138      BODY
      LayoutTable 0x23e069230010        TABLE class="vrt-header"
        LayoutTableSection 0x23e069240010   THEAD
          LayoutTableRow (anonymous) 0x23e06924c010
            LayoutTableCell (anonymous) 0x23e069254010
              LayoutBlockFlow 0x23e069224260    TR
                LayoutTable (anonymous) 0x23e0692301b0
                  LayoutTableSection (anonymous) 0x23e069240188
                    LayoutTableRow (anonymous) 0x23e06924c128
                      LayoutTableCell 0x23e069254150    TH
                      LayoutTableCell 0x23e069254290    TH class="vertical"
                        LayoutBlockFlow (positioned) 0x23e069224388 DIV class="vertical"
                          LayoutText 0x23e069264010 #text "Republican"
                      LayoutTableCell 0x23e0692543d0    TH class="vertical"
                        LayoutBlockFlow (positioned) 0x23e0692244b0 DIV class="vertical"
                          LayoutText 0x23e0692640e0 #text "Democrat"
                      LayoutTableCell 0x23e069254510    TH class="vertical"
                        LayoutBlockFlow (positioned) 0x23e0692245d8 DIV class="vertical"
                          LayoutText 0x23e0692641b0 #text "Libertarian"
                      LayoutTableCell 0x23e069254650    TH class="vertical"
                        LayoutBlockFlow (positioned) 0x23e069224700 DIV class="vertical"
                          LayoutText 0x23e069264280 #text "Green"
        LayoutTableSection (anonymous) 0x23e069240300
          LayoutTableRow (anonymous) 0x23e06924c240
            LayoutTableCell (anonymous) 0x23e069254790
              LayoutBlockFlow 0x23e069224828    TBODY
                LayoutTable (anonymous) 0x23e069230350
                  LayoutTableSection (anonymous) 0x23e069240478
                    LayoutTableRow 0x23e06924c358   TR
                      LayoutTableCell 0x23e0692548d0    TD
                        LayoutText 0x23e069264350   #text "\nAlabama\n"
                      LayoutTableCell 0x23e069254a10    TD
                        LayoutText 0x23e069264420   #text "\n65\n"
                      LayoutTableCell 0x23e069254b50    TD
                        LayoutText 0x23e0692644f0   #text "\n25\n"
                      LayoutTableCell 0x23e069254c90    TD
                        LayoutText 0x23e0692645c0   #text "\n10\n"
                      LayoutTableCell 0x23e069254dd0    TD
                        LayoutText 0x23e069264690   #text "\n0\n"
                    LayoutTableRow 0x23e06924c470   TR
                      LayoutTableCell 0x23e069254f10    TD
                        LayoutText 0x23e069264760   #text "\nAlaska\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did everything you requested, all 4 here, nearly with css-only.

- Test it: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/246746/show or
- see the code fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/246746/

I could also code the 3rd question with only CSS! I set the height using padding and a div wrapper for th. Like this:

```
th.vertical {
  height: 0;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  text-align: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.verticalWrapper {
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Note the `padding-top: 100%`

1) I created a table container div for this one.

```
.tableContainer {
  height: 400px;
  width: 500px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

For iOS it is simply a matter of preference: https://heresthethingblog.com/2015/03/10/mac-tip-macs-scroll-bars/

2) Since we are rotating the element, we need a height that is equal to width. I used css to do that and you can read related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30789888/3554534)

3) I used css transform.

4) Used the same method as [@takit-isy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50866716/3554534)

Comment: The header is not frozen.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not an easy task. I would replace your tables with divs.

i wrote an example so you have an idea how it could look:

```
    <div class='table'>
  <div class='header'>
  <div ><p class="vertical first">&nbsp;</p></div>
  <div ><p class="vertical">Republican</p></div>
      <div ><p class="vertical">Democrat</p></div>
      <div ><p class="vertical">Libertarian</p></div>
      <div ><p class="vertical">Green</p></div>
  </div>
  <div class='scroller'>
 <div class='content'>
    <div>
      <div>Alabama</div>
      <div>65</div>
      <div>25</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>0</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Alaska</div>
      <div>65</div>
      <div>25</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>0</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Arizona</div>
      <div>65</div>
      <div>25</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>0</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Arzkansas</div>
      <div>65</div>
      <div>25</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>0</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Arzkansas</div>
      <div>65</div>
      <div>25</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>0</div>
    </div>
      <div>
      <div>Arzkansas</div>
      <div>65</div>
      <div>25</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>0</div>
    </div>
  <div>
      <div>Arzkansas</div>
      <div>65</div>
      <div>25</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>0</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Arzkansas</div>
      <div>65</div>
      <div>25</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>0</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Arzkansas</div>
      <div>65</div>
      <div>25</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>0</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Arzkansas</div>
      <div>65</div>
      <div>25</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>0</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Arzkansas</div>
      <div>65</div>
      <div>25</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>0</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Arzkansas</div>
      <div>65</div>
      <div>25</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>0</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Arzkansas</div>
      <div>65</div>
      <div>25</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>0</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Arzkansas</div>
      <div>65</div>
      <div>25</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>0</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>Arzkansas</div>
      <div>65</div>
      <div>25</div>
      <div>10</div>
      <div>0</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  </div>

.table{
  height:300px;
  width:500px;

}
.vertical{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  width:56px;
  margin:0px;
}
.first{
  padding-right: 268px;
}
.header{
  height:150px;
  width:500px;
  display:flex;
}
.header>div{
    display:flex;
  }
  .scroller{
     height:calc(100% - 50px);
     overflow-y:scroll;
  }
  .content{
    width:100%;
    display:table;
  }
.content>div{
  display:table-row;
  width:500px;
}
.content>div>div{
  display:table-cell;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xjhun7zf/6/`

(it is not perfect, because i wrote that in 20 minutes)

if you have 2 container, one for the head and one for the body, then you can set the head to a static position with a fixed height and your body with the rest height;